# App Linking Failed after building in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, arm64, huawei-analytics

When I build my react native project in Xcode it builds Successfully and on linking time to simulator it shows the error in one of the library called HuaweiAnalytics.

The Error is like below:

**"In /ios/Pods/HiAnalytics/HiAnalytics.framework/HiAnalytics(HiAnalytics_vers.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/ios/Pods/HiAnalytics/HiAnalytics.framework/HiAnalytics' for architecture arm64".**

I tried to change the 'Excluded Architecture' in Xcode to 'arm64' and I have the M1 chip Mac and Xcode version is '14.3.1 (14E300c)'.

Does anybody knows what's the cause of this issue?